# Change underline-color of child-elements in FF and Opera (works in IE, Safari and Chrome)

Tags: html, css

**Story:**
I have a link which has some text. A part of the link should be styled a bit different (different size and color).

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Lorem Ipsum <span>Lorem Ipsum</span> Lorem Ipsum</a>
```

CSS:

```
a { color: blue; text-decoration: underline; }
a span { color: yellow; font-size: 2em; }
```

**Problem:**
Whatever I do, I can't get a good way to have the line under the text of the span in the same color as the text.

The only solution I can see is to set *text-decoration: none* on the a-tag and set it for each child. But this does not seem like a good way to me.

I've tested this in Firefox v12 (Windows and Ubuntu), Opera v11, IE v7, IE v9, Safari v5.1 and Chrome (Nightly) ...

Only Firefox and Opera seem to have this issue (Opera even worse than Firefox but I don't care that much about Opera).

*EDIT:*
My goal here is not to totally get rid of the line but to change the color (by whatever solution). As I see out of the answer Chris wrote I think it has to be something like over-painting. That's at least how it looks like in IE and the Webkit-Browsers.

**Example:**
Here's a link to an extended example:
http://jsfiddle.net/r2dhb/3/

**Update:**
There's definitively something that will change in CSS3 http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#decoration but I don't care because this stuff is not supported in any of the browsers :)

Comment: Two things I will note is that this isn't limited to content of an `<a>` tag and if you change the spans to inline-block they no longer get the underline but you do then of course have different problems with the layout. I thougth these observations might help though. :)

Comment: fascinating. Looks like a browser bug to me

Comment: It looks like it may be as per spec. The `<a>` is being underlined and the style on its children shouldn't effect it. It is akin to if you were to apply a border to the element. You wouldnt' expect it to stop where the child elements were... I'm trying to find a suitably non-ambiguous quote from w3 on the issue before posting as an answer...

Comment: @Chris As text-decoration is meant for inline and not for block-styles I would expect that it differs in the behavior from border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my workaround (Firefox only):

```
a span.test3 { text-decoration: underline; vertical-align: 4%; }
```

Thus the child (span) underline should hide the parent (a) underline.

Of course the underline is still thicker, but maybe you can change that in CSS3?!

Thanks.

Comment: I kind-of accept this workaround as it does not completely destroy the appearance in IE and the Webkit-Browsers ... But still - in Webkit the line seems broken now.

Answer (score 2):

Quotes are from http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-text-decoration

> The 'text-decoration' property on descendant elements cannot have any
>   effect on the decoration of the ancestor. In determining the position
>   of and thickness of text decoration lines, user agents may consider
>   the font sizes of and dominant baselines of descendants, but must use
>   the same baseline and thickness on each line. Relatively positioning a
>   descendant moves all text decorations affecting it along with the
>   descendant's text; it does not affect calculation of the decoration's
>   initial position on that line.

The above quote isn't as explicit as it could be but implies that the parent element will have underline no matter what the state of its children's underline are. It also suggests that the underline thickness should be consistent throughout.

> The color(s) required for the text decoration must be derived from the
>   'color' property value of the element on which 'text-decoration' is
>   set. The color of decorations must remain the same even if descendant
>   elements have different 'color' values.

This second quote suggests that the colour should indeed remain unchanged for a given elements underline. So the not changing colour when going underneath the yellow text is as per the spec.

I would agree that there feels like there should be some way of allowing you to turn that underline off but I think your work around of applying underline to individual divs may be all you've got.

Comment: My goal is not really to get rid of the underline for one child-element, but to get him a different underline-color. It would be totally fine if the green line (from the .test3 tag) would be kind of over-painted by the yellow one as it is for the .test2 tag.

Comment: @SimonSimCity - That the way I did it in my post!